GTK apps UIs look broken in Debian
What is the problem and how to fix it? gdmap looks like this:

I think it has to do with GTK. I'm using Debian 12 with KDE and Wayland. On a nearly identical machine gdmap looks fine. I have libgtk-3-0 and libgtk-4-1 installed and when I enter sudo apt-get install gdmap nothing is asked to be installed and I already tried reinstalling. Other apps like Firefox and Lutris look normal. It's not only gdmap but also other apps, namely VeraCrypt which I installed locally and GParted. The icons are missing.

Does this help?

No, it didn't. Changed the GTK theme to every option in the dropdown and also changed the KDE theme (in system settings Application Style). Look like before.
